# Что означает предложение?

Tags: фразеология

Что означает предложение "Таким образом, вопрос о допустимости ситуационного плана как доказательства не может ставиться."
Может ситуационный план быть принят как доказательство или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Данное предложение указывает лишь на то, что допустимость ситуационного плана как доказательства не может оспариваться, и в равной степени возможны два варианта:

- ситуационный план однозначно допустим в качестве доказательства и с этим нельзя спорить;
- ситуационный план однозначно НЕ допустим в качестве доказательства и с этим нельзя спорить.

При этом данное предложение не содержит четких указаний на то, какой из этих вариантов более вероятен.

Answer (score 0):

Вне контекста из этого предложения *нельзя* заключить, что говорящий настаивает на допустимости "ситуационного плана" в качестве доказательства. Само по себе предложение воспринимается по смыслу так же, как и в более ясном варианте: "вопрос о допустимости *или недопустимости...*". Далее может последовать: "Конечно же, такое доказательство допустимо [= недопустимо]".

Утверждать можно лишь одно: вопрос о допустимости (или недопустимости) названного в качестве доказательства **нет смысла ставить** по причине ранее изложенного. Говорящий либо обосновал перед этим один из двух выводов, либо он говорит о некорректности самой постановки вопроса.